# Number of prime ideals in coordinate ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, arithmetic-geometry

I want to prove the following theorem, I have some idea and need some push:

Let $f \in \bar{k}[x,y]$ be a non-constant polynomial. Let $I$ be any non-zero ideal in $C_f = \bar{k}[x,y]/(f)$. Show that the prime ideals of $C_f$ that contain $I$ is a finite set.

My idea is that if I can show that $C_f /I$ has finitely many prime ideals, then we are done. This is because "prime ideals of $C_f$ containing $I$" are in 1-1 correspondence with the "ideals of prime ideals $C_f/I$". I could not done a nice setup, so any help would be great.

Comment: can you translate the algebraic statement into a geometric statement? what geometric object corresponds to $k[x,y]$, and what geometric object corresponds to $C_f$?

Comment: I think you also want $f$ irreducible.

Comment: Well, we need $f$ to be irreducible in order to get a prime ideal and $C_f$ to be a domain. Plus, we should say that for some $g$, for any map from $C_f$ to $C_g$, we can find a map from $C(Z_f, \bar{k})$ to $C(Z_g, \bar{k})$.

Comment: And I stuck here.

Comment: I think you can find generating sets of all those things as $\overline{k}[x,y], \overline{k}[x,y]/(f)$ and $\overline{k}$ modules and obtain $\overline{k}[x,y]/(f,I)$ is a finitely generated $\overline{k}$ module. Since $\overline{k}$ is a field it won't have so many ideals

Comment: As @LordSharktheUnknown said, you need $f$ to irreducible. Consider the following example: $f=xy \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and $I$ be ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(f)$ generated by the image of $x$. Then for any $a \in \mathbb{C}$, the image of the ideal $(x,y-a) \subset \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(f)$ is a prime ideal, and of course this set is not finite.

Comment: Okay, taking $f$ to be irreducible, what can I do next?